# If the digit sum function would be valid for base 1, would it mean that the digit sum of n in base 1 be equal n?

Tags: natural-numbers

Let us define $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ and let us define the digit sum function for the base $b$ as $F_b(n)$ (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum)).

Also as mentioned in the previous wikipedia link the base is $b \ge 2$.

What I am asking myself is if $b$ could be $1$, would this mean that $F_1(n) = n$?

If this should be true then we could say that the basic counting is similar (or equal?) to counting of $1$'s for the number $n$ in base $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base $n$ has digits $0, 1, ..., n-1$

Base 1 would only have $0$ as a digit, so is impossible to use as a way to represent numbers.

Therefore $b\ge2$

Comment: I guess we could define the base b representation of a number $n$ as the lexicographically first sequence of non-negative integers $c_i$ such that $\sum_i c_i b_i  = n$.  That would give usual base $b$ representations for $b > 1$ and tallies for $b = 1$.

Comment: Oh that didn't quite work because you would prefer e.g. 111000 to 111. I wonder it can be fixed cleanly, though.

Comment: My thoughts were that $n$ in base $1$ would be a concatenation of $1$'s $n$-time. Therefore I was suggesting that $F_1(n)=n$, but maybe I have a flaw in my understanding. Also does base $n$ has only $n-1$ digits? Should it not be digits $0, 1, ..., n-1$?

Comment: Well spotted. I’ve changed my answer.